# Can a boolean be asked?

Tags: c#

So Im new into coding. And my question is, can u make someone type if a question is yes or no and if it its true using, the swith statement say its correct. But I want to make it that the answer can be only yes or no and each bool is true or false. If not what can I do to make this work?

```
using System;

namespace FliptheIntegerBoolean
{
   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {

           bool yes;
           bool no;

           Console.Write("Is a dog a animal? ");
           bool yes = Convert.ToBoolean( Console.ReadLine()); 



           switch (yes)
           {
               case true:
                   Console.WriteLine("yes it is");
                   break;
               default:
                   Console.WriteLine("U dumb?");
                   break;
           }

           
           switch (no)
           {
               case true:
                   Console.WriteLine("Then what is it? XDD");
                   break;
               default:
                   Console.WriteLine("U dumb?");
                   break;
           }   




           


          


           Console.ReadKey();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: You won't need 2 switch statements. Only 1 is enough, and instead of parsing to boolean just pass the string input to the switch and look for "Yes", "No", default. You don't need a boolean cast at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `if ... else...` statement

```cs
using System;

namespace FliptheIntegerBoolean {

  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      Console.Write("Is a dog an animal? ");
      string answer = Console.ReadLine(); 

      if (answer == "yes") {
        Console.WriteLine("yes it is");
      } else if (answer == "no") {
        Console.WriteLine("Then what is it? XDD");
      } else {
        Console.WriteLine("U dumb?");
      }

      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And can the bool be asked with a yes or no? Or for that I must use a string?

Comment: Doesnt work. It gives me the error -> the expression '=' is not valid. I mean Its way better to do it with strings but I still want to know if I can do it with booleans.

Comment: @Gonzalo can you explain more about doing it with Booleans?
Console gets string a input and you can cast the input to Boolean in C#.

Comment: Syntax error because of just and extra "=" sign. Change answer === "no" to answer == "no"

Comment: @HamidNoahdi O yeah my bad, got it fixed already. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want need result as Boolean

```cs
namespace FliptheIntegerBoolean
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool yes;
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Is a dog a animal? ");
                string answer = Console.ReadLine();
                if (answer.ToLower() == "yes")
                {
                    yes = true;
                }
                else if (answer.ToLower() == "no")
                {
                    yes = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Then what is it? XDD");
                    continue;
                }

                Console.WriteLine(yes ? "yes it is" : "Then what is it? XDD");
            }
        }
    }
}
```